# Finding Solution of 2nd order ODE near a regular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I am having trouble solving this problem and could use some hints, ideas or a solid walk through that I could use to clear up the foggy areas.

$$x^2y''+3xy'+(1+x)y=0$$

I have proven that $X_0=0$ is a regular singular point by showing that $~P(0)=0~$ and that the limit as $~x\to 0~$ for both $~p(o),~ q(o)~$ are finite.

I know that the indicial equation is then:

$r(r-1)+3r+1=0$

which gives $r_1=r_2=-1$

**This is where I get a bit unsure**

Because we have repeated roots, I believe we look for a solution $Y_1$ of the form:

$$X^{r_1} {\sum^{\infty}_1} A_n(r_1)X^n$$

but I have two different ideas about the method of finding $A_n$. I think we find $A_n$ as:

$$\frac{1}{F(r+n)} {\sum^{n-1}_{k=o}A_k[(r+k)P_{n-k}}+q_{n-k}]$$

and here:

$P_0=3$ $P_n$=0 all else 
$q_0=q_1=1$ $q_n$=o all else

which comes directly from the expansion of $xp(x)$ and $X^2q(x)$ matched to p and q.

My solution: $$X^{-1}[1+x-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{36}x^3]$$

book solution: $$\frac{1}{x}{\sum^{\infty}_0}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{(n!)^2}$$

that is for $Y_1(x)$. I obviously made a book keeping error with negative signs while calculating my values of $A_n$ so that isn't a big deal.

my problem is with the solutions of $y_2(x)$ which the book gives as: 
$$y_1(x)ln(x)-\frac{2}{x}[1-{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}} \frac{(-1)^nH_n}{(n!)^2}x^n]$$

I just can't get my answer to look anything remotely like the provided solution. Can anyone help me out?

I want to add that I added the Bessel function tag because this came from the Bessel function section of our HW. Perhaps I am supposed to apply those methods? It just doesn't seem of the correct form.

Comment: Amzoti - no, no it wasn't. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Amzoti - added that information near the bottom of the problem. I included both the book solution and my solution (for y1) and the book solution for y2.

Answer (score 0):

may i add that if you you realise that
$$
x^2y'' + 3xy' + (1+x)y = x^2y'' + 2xy' + xy' + y + xy =0
$$
or
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y'\right) + \dfrac{d}{dx}(xy) + xy = 0
$$
let $v = yx$
we find

$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)'\right) + v' + v &=& -v' + (v'x)' + v' + v\\
&=& xv'' + v' + v = 0
\end{align}
$$
thus try solving 
$$
x\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2} + \dfrac{dv}{dx} + v = 0
$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: That is brilliant.

Comment: @mathtastic no worries. Hope you made head way now :)